# .NET Framework security issue

Tags: vb.net

When I run my application on my friend's Windows 7 computer, I get a .NET security error.

Here is a screenshot

[alt text http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/1340/94161244.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/1340/94161244.png)

and here is manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="Myapp.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
            If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
            requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
            compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

How can i fix this in visual basic 2010 ?

thanks

EDIT:  I made a temporary fix like this

```
    Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

            Dim a As New WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
            If Not a.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) Then
                MsgBox("Please Run the application as administrator")
                e.Cancel = True
            End If

End Sub
```

EDIT 2: I also realized that my friend's win 7 is kinda broken, it does not even load SSL certf. of the web pages. weird

Comment: Please show us the details (maybe it contains a stracktrace?). If it contains a stacktrace, show us the code at that position.

Comment: i just use "RegistryKey" and "Application.CommonAppDataRegistry" it gives error because of registry access request i guess

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to *write* or *read* from the common appdata registry?

- If you only need to *read*: Change your code such that your `RegistryKey` only requires read-only permissions.
- If you need to *write*: Only administrators can write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, which is where the common appdata resides. Thus, your application will require administrative permissions, which requires *elevation* in Windows Vista or 7. At this point, you should again make a decision:

  - If it is really important that this data is shared between users and it's OK that only admins can use your software: Start your application with `Right-mouse-button/Run as administrator` or add a manifest as suggested by Rubens.
  - If it's OK for the data to be stored *per user*, use `Application.UserAppDataRegistry` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look here: [Demand UAC elevation for an application by adding a manifest using mt.exe](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/28/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Demand-UAC-elevation-for-an-application-by-adding-a-manifest-using-mt.exe.aspx)

Comment: i read it but there is no Build events tab in visual basic 2010, i dont know, actually i couldn't understand that text as a vb beginner :) but i added manifest info to my question

Comment: You need to right-click your project and select Properties; There you'll see Build events tab; (well, I have one with a console project type)

Comment: sorry but really there is no that tab on properties in visual basic 2010

Comment: just saw that... but what about that UAC button on Application tab?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a security demand on the method for the specified key, I think this causes UAC to kick in if needed. Change the `Write` attribute to whatever key you're accessing.

```
    <System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission(Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Write:="HKLM\Software")> _
Private Shared Sub Bob()

End Sub
```

Or adding this to your AssemblyInfo.vb:

```
<Assembly: System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission(Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, ViewAndModify:="HKLM\Software")>
```

Comment: should i add this to the function where i am accessing ?

Comment: You can add the first attribute to the class or method that you're calling, the second you can add to the AssemblyInfo.vb file (in the solution explorer you'll need to click "Show All Files").

Answer (score 0):

Please change,

**this line**

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

**Into**

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

in your manifest file.